# combining properties in an array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add a property to the items in this array called `fullName` that combines `firstname` and `lastname`?

```
let employeeNames = [ { firstName: "Collin", lastName: "Sexton" }, { firstName: "Darius", lastName: "Garland" } ]
```

Expected result:

```
employeeNames = [ { firstName: "Collin", lastName: "Sexton", fullName: "Collin Sexton" }, { firstName: "Darius", lastName: "Garland", fullName: "Darius Garland" } ]
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Use `map` employeeNames.map(k=>({...k,fullName:``${k.firstName} ${k.lastName}``}))

Comment: I suspect the reason for the closure is that you did not include any code showing what you tried thus far in solving this problem.  If you update with your attempt and what is failing the question may be able to be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over employee name using `array#map` and generate the full name.

```js
let employeeNames = [ { firstName: "Collin", lastName: "Sexton" }, { firstName: "Darius", lastName: "Garland" } ],
    output = employeeNames.map(o => ({...o, fullName: `${o.firstName} ${o.lastName}`}))
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the first and last name fields to a new field by destructuring the object and combining the values.

```js
let employeeNames = [
  { firstName: "Collin", lastName: "Sexton" },
  { firstName: "Darius", lastName: "Garland" }
];

let result = employeeNames.map(({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  ...rest
}) => ({
  ...rest,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let employeeNames = [ { firstName: "Collin", lastName: "Sexton" }, { firstName: "Darius", lastName: "Garland" } ]

employeeNames = employeeNames.map(employeeName => ({...employeeName, fullName: employeeName.firstName + " " + employeeName.lastName}))

console.log(employeeNames);
```